# How can I have a range slider with negative values?

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I'm working with slider `<input type="range" />` with:

- minimum value: -20
- maximum value: -90
- step         : 15
- the value should be: -20, -35, -50, -65, -80
- the value of -90 will never reached because of the step constraint.

It works with positive value (min: 20, max: 90, step: 15) but I don't have an idea dealing with negative value.
Can you help me?

[image: Screenshot]

[Codesandbox.io link](https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-with-negative-value-jqe02?file=/index.html)

Comment: Reverse your min and max `<input type="range" min="-90" max="-20" step="15"/>` -90 is smaller than -20

Comment: but the min_value impacting the step, so the value = min + (step * N)

Comment: Did you delete your code sandbox? Please add the code to the post

Comment: No. I've updated the link to make sure it's not broken

Comment: <input type="range" min="-80" max="-20" step="15" value="-20"/>

Comment: I revised the min/max="-90", so the slider never reached the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set min value to `-80` and add `padding-left` to the slider to let the user think that `-90` is the min value.

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=range]");

for (const slider of sliders) {
  slider.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.value = e.target.value;
  });

  slider.nextElementSibling.value = slider.value;
}
```

```css
input {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="-80" max="-20" step="15" />
<output></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it by simply using HTML as -90 is lower than -20 so you cannot set `min="-20"` `max="-80"`. But by using this trick you may achieve your output.

Keep the HTML as:

```
<input type="range" min="20" max="90" step="15"/>
<output></output>
```

Change your JavaScript to:

```
for (const slider of sliders) {
  slider.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.value = "-" + e.target.value;
  });

  slider.nextElementSibling.value = "-" + slider.value;
}
```

Comment: but it requires to modify the server side validation too

Comment: but the closest solution is padding trick by @Tom, not the perfect solution but it works for me. The drawback is need to calculate how much the padding added.